# Getting SCNNode Bounding Size in Meters

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to wrap an SCNPlane around a SCNNode. I'm using ARKit so everything is measured in meters, but when I get the `boundingBox`, I get measurements in some other unit. I looked at Apple's documentation, and they don't specify what the units are.

For example, one of nodes is roughly 3 meters wide, but it says its 26 units.

I could do a rough division to get a constant and use that to do the unit conversions, but I was wondering if there's a less hacky way to do it?

```
let textContainerSize = textBodyNode.boundingBox
let xSize = textContainerSize.max.x - textContainerSize.min.x
let ySize = textContainerSize.max.y - textContainerSize.min.y
print("size")
print(xSize, ySize) // <-- returns (26,2) 
let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: xSize, height: ySize)
```

Answer (score 3):

One SceneKit unit is one meter in `ARKit` but the [`boundingBox`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnboundingvolume/2034705-boundingbox) is defined in the nodes local coordinate system. So your node probably has a parent with a scale different from 1.